# How to get PHP Storm to use PHPDoc info in intellisense?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have wordpress set up inside PHP Storm and I am trying to get it to show extra information in the pop-up intellisense.

If I go <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> I can see the comment is there correctly for function I am calling.  If I go <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> then I get the doc window appear with all info in.

But when I am typing function and hit the first parenthesis it just gives me the variable name and type from the declaration with no extra information.

Is this just how PHP Storm works and I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> every time for additional information or should I be able to see the extra info in the intellisense like you can in other IDE?

Comment: At the close voter: The description of your suggested reason says *unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming* - this does, so I suggest you retract your vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this just how PHP Storm works..

Correct.

This way pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> will allow to see docs for element under caret.

Your only reasonable option right now is to make Quick Doc popup sticky so that it will still display old info. For that -- either click on "pin" icon or invoke <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> once more.

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23913 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress (it is about showing more info about current parameter similarly to how Visual Studio does).

Comment: Thanks.  I enabled auto pop-up in settings like it said on the linked issue but it doesn't seem to work.  I also checked option for full signature but didn't do anything. One of the comments I see on issue that they don't see how it could be useful is crazy.  You get a function that accepts 5 int values or something, it's damn helpful after you enter each value to have a description popup of what that value does.  It's not the end of the world, I can just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> but it takes me out of my flow.  I guess I'll just get used to it.

Comment: *" I enabled auto pop-up in settings"* -- the one for `Parameter Info` (can be invoked via `Ctrl+P`)? It shows that small info about function parameters. Or was that `Autopopup documentation` -- that's different and works during code completion popup only.

Comment: Instead of doing `Ctrl+Q` multiple times .. just pin it permanently somewhere on the screen (left/right panel or so) -- when visible the next Ctrl+Q (manual or automatic) will show docs just there.

Comment: I do have it pinned, I just realised I can ctrl + Q on different suggestions which is cool but I cant get it to work automatic.  Does the automatic work?  For me it just stays on the last one I did Ctrl + Q on forever until I do it again.

Comment: ctrl + P brings up print for me btw. ctrl + shift + I brings up the declaration in a popup but pinned that also does not update automatically.

Comment: *"ctrl + P brings up print for me btw."* -- `View | Parameter Info`

Comment: *" For me it just stays on the last one I did Ctrl + Q on forever until I do it again."* Once pinned, there is a button next to "X" called `Auto-update from source` -- but I think it will not be that useful as it will show docs under caret (which *I believe* is not what you are after)

Comment: right got it, thats ctrl alt space for me.  That does update the window but no easier than hitting ctrl + Q really.  I guess I am just being fussy and should stop worrying and write some code :)

Comment: AHA! Yes, I didnt see the auto update button.  I am now a happy camper.  Thank you very much for your help!